# A high school coordinate geometry problem

Tags: geometry

What we know:

- Half-line $AB$  $(A_x, A_y)$, $(B_x, B_y)$
- Point $C$ $(C_x, C_y)$
- Length $d$

The question: what is the length of section *x*

Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Zev Chonoles, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Since ultimately you want to find the side length of a triangle, your setup should be the same as if you were  trying to solve that triangle. You have one side ($d$), what are ways you know to get other sides or angles?

Comment: @user55012 Do you know what vectors and the dot product is?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

$x=\sqrt{d^2-h^2}+\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$

where

$r=\sqrt{(B_x-C_x)^2+(B_y-C_y)^2}$

$h=\frac{|A_xB_y-A_yB_x+C_x(A_y-B_y)-C_y(A_x-B_x)|}{\sqrt{(A_x-B_x)^2+(A_y-B_y)^2}}$

$r$ is the distance from C to B and $h$ is the distance from C to the line passing through A and B. 
No need to solve quadratic equations.

Comment: Wow, I think this is the answer to my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: My math teacher said it was good. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood the problem's setting:

1) Since you're given the points $\,A,B\,$ you can then easily find out that line's general formula $$\,y=mx+n\,$$

2) You know the point C and you know it's distance from a general point $\,(x_0,mx_0+n)\,$ on the line $\,AB\,:\,y=mx+n\,$ , so that you can now use the distance's formula

$$d^2=(C_x-x_o)^2+(C_y-mx_0-n)^2$$

to get two points on $\,AB\,$ that fit.

3) Relying upon the diagram, you only have to choose the point (that you found in (2)) on $\,AB\,$ that is the farest away from A and then calculate its distance from $\,B\,$ in order to get $\,x\,$